# Android webview load website

Tags: android, webview

I have a webview and load webpage it it. Works Fine.

But the problem is, "When I click any link from webpage redirected to browser not in webpage created".

I want to open it in same webpage.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want more control over where a clicked link load, create your own WebViewClient that overrides the **shouldOverrideUrlLoading()** method.

Adding the following code before loadUrl() in your webview.

```
 webview.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {
 public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
      view.loadUrl(url);
      return true;
       }
 });
```

More details Refer [Web Apps in WebView](http://developer.android.com/guide/webapps/webview.html#HandlingNavigation)

Answer (score 0):

Create a class extending WebViewClient:

```
private class MyBrowser extends WebViewClient {

    @Override
    public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String urlNewString) {
        view.loadUrl(urlNewString);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {

    }
}
```

Then set webViewClient to your webview Initially:

```
webView.setWebViewClient(new MyBrowser());
```

Answer (score 0):

use the following code in `AndroidMenifest.xml` inside the particular activity  tag

```
<intent-filter>
    <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE"/>
</intent-filter>
```

Answer (score 0):

Here i have a sample Activity class for you.

Whenever you try to open a link in the WebView the browser opens that link because **you have not used any WebViewClient in your code**. Please refer to the following code that i am sharing with you!

```
public class WebViewClientDemoActivity extends Activity {
    /** Called when the activity is first created. */

    WebView web;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        web = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webview01);

        // Setting the WebView Client for the WebView over here
        web.setWebViewClient(new myWebClient());
        web.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        web.loadUrl("http://www.google.com");
    }

      // The WebViewClient class
    public class myWebClient extends WebViewClient
    {
        @Override
        public void onPageStarted(WebView view, String url, Bitmap favicon) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            super.onPageStarted(view, url, favicon);
        }

        @Override
        public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            view.loadUrl(url);
            return true;

        }
    }

    // To handle "Back" key press event for WebView to go back to previous screen.
    @Override
    public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) 
    {
        if ((keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK) && web.canGoBack()) {
            web.goBack();
            return true;
        }
        return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);
    }
}
```

Please let me know if it works! :)

Answer (score 0):

Just add the following lines in your code

```
private class MyWebViewClient extends WebViewClient {
    @Override
    public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url)
    {
         view.loadUrl(url);
        return true;
    }

    public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onPageFinished(view, url);

    }
}
```

And set above webview client for your webview like this:

```
 webView.setWebViewClient(new MyWebViewClient());
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity  {
   Button b1;
   EditText ed1;

   private WebView wv1;
   @Override
   protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
      super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
      setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

      b1=(Button)findViewById(R.id.button);
      ed1=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText);

      wv1=(WebView)findViewById(R.id.webView);
      wv1.setWebViewClient(new MyBrowser());

      b1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
         @Override
         public void onClick(View v) {
            String url = ed1.getText().toString();

            wv1.getSettings().setLoadsImagesAutomatically(true);
            wv1.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
            wv1.setScrollBarStyle(View.SCROLLBARS_INSIDE_OVERLAY);
            wv1.loadUrl(url);
         }
      });
   }

   private class MyBrowser extends WebViewClient {
      @Override
      public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
         view.loadUrl(url);
         return true;
      }
   }

   @Override
   public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
      // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
      getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
      return true;
   }

   @Override
   public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
      // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
      // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
      // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.

      int id = item.getItemId();

      //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
      if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
         return true;
      }
      return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
   }
}
```

For further reference you can visit the below link

http://www.tutorialspoint.com/android/android_webview_layout.htm